# Is "quantum monism" a new interpretation of quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I must admit I am a little confused on the following article:

Here is a link.

https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/quantum-monism-could-save-the-soul-of-physics/

Here is the part that confuses me.
"As such, quantum monism has the potential to save the soul of science: the conviction that there is a unique, comprehensible and fundamental reality."

This is in the last paragraph.

Isn't this true regardless the the interpretation of quantum mechanics?

I assume by "fundamental reality"  we are talking about the properties having definite states and nothing more.

Comment: When asking about context of a paper, please copy the relevant passage and give specific details what you don't understand (see [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11144/25301) for more details). Otherwise we can only guess at what you don't understand.

Comment: I think I fixed it.  I said in one sentence what I want to know.   The only thing is I am not sure how to ask without including the article that it refers to.   Maybe I can better word the original question as it is presented?   Any suggestions?

Comment: I was not the first to ask.. ( apparently someone else suffered from the same malady I did )  ..in Quora ....it was answered.